# What causes these shapes in the coast of the Levant?

Tags: geomorphology, coastal

Along the coast of the Levant (maybe also in other places), there are some very distinct discontinuities such as these. It may be nothing at all, but they stood out to me. Now I was wondering if there was a specific reason for the these specific discontinuities to arise.

The one in the picture is at Beirut, but also slight to the south there are several smaller discontinuities in the coast lines. They all seem to be small pieces of north facing coast line.

Some I noticed where at Beirut, Saadiyat, between Jiyeh and Jadra, Rmayleh, Iskandarounah, Haifa, Tripoli (lebanon), Ras al Basit, Om al-toyour, Burj Islam, 1 at Jableh and 1 just north of Jableh, Hamat and Hraiche.

I am aware not all of these are on the same scale and there are many more. Especially smaller ones, which I did not list. But they do all seem to have a similar shape, leaving me to wonder whether they could have a similar origin.

[image: Distinct discontinuity along the coast of the levant.]

Comment: I know there is people here more qualified than me to answer this. But to me look like a delta, in that case there should be a large river discharging its waters there. Now, the shape could be explained by wind and currents patterns that moves come of the sediment northwards.

Comment: I don't think these are delta's. Some of the places named have a small river, but nothing significant. And all these location are quite rocky (Several large pieces of stone visible/steep hills)

Comment: Because it's nature and nature is rather unruly. Look at the land: It's rocky, hilly, even a bit mountaineous. It is to be expected that such formations don't form a smooth line to any side, not even to the sea.